# How to pass values and use this function

Tags: python, list, parsing, formula

Hi I have the following code .

```
import csv
import math

EASTING_BASE = 500
NORTHING_BASE = 500

def main():
    global NORTHING_BASE
    global EASTING_BASE

     for i, a in getStationCoords():
        statione = int(i)
        stationn = int(a)
        print statione,stationn

    stationEasting = int(getStationCoords()[0][0])
    stationNorthing = int(getStationCoords()[0][1])

    for i in range(0, len(eastingList)):
        print "Co-ordinates (" + str(eastingList[i]) + "," + str(northingList[i]) + ")"
        print calculateDistance(NORTHING_BASE, EASTING_BASE, northingList[i], eastingList[i])
        print calculateBearing(NORTHING_BASE, EASTING_BASE, northingList[i], eastingList[i])


def getStationCoords():
    listStation = []
    a_reader = None
    a_reader     = open('data.csv', 'rU')
    a_csv_reader = csv.reader(a_reader)
    a_csv_reader.next()  
    for i in [row[-2:] for row in a_csv_reader]:
     listStation.append(i)
    a_reader.close()

    count = 0
    sum   = 0.0
    a_reader     = open('data.csv', 'rU')
    a_csv_reader = csv.reader(a_reader)

    #for row in a_csv_reader:
     #       if count != 0 and row[0] != '':
      #          sum = sum + float(row[0])
       #     count = count + 1


    #print 'Number of lines is:',count
    #print 'Sum is:',sum

    return listStation

def main2():

    global NORTHING_BASE
    global EASTING_BASE

    eastingList = []
    northingList = []

    def calculateDistance(northingOne, eastingOne, northingTwo, eastingTwo):
    # Determine differences in eastings and northings
    deltaEasting = eastingTwo - eastingOne
    deltaNorthing = northingTwo - northingOne

    # We don't need to worry about +/- as using pythag below
    distance = (deltaEasting **2 + deltaNorthing **2) **0.5

    # Return the value for distance
    return distance

def calculateBearing(northingOne, eastingOne, northingTwo, eastingTwo):
    diffEasting = eastingTwo - eastingOne
    diffNorthing = northingTwo - northingOne

    # Work out if in QI/II or QIII/IV
    if diffEasting >= 0:
        # This is in QI/II
        if diffNorthing >0:
            # This is in QI
            bearing = math.atan(diffEasting / diffNorthing)
        else:
            # This is in QII
            bearing = math.pi - math.atan(diffEasting / abs(diffNorthing))
    else:
        # This is in QIII/IV
        if diffNorthing >0:
            # This is in QIV
            bearing = 2 * math.pi - math.atan(abs(diffEasting) / diffNorthing)
        else:
            # This is in QIII
            bearing = math.pi + math.atan(abs(diffEasting) / abs(diffNorthing))

    # Return the value
    return bearing


main2()
main()
```

Ok so I know that I will have to place values in the easting and northing lists. Below. My first function main() produces the following

```
476050 7709929
473971 7707713
465676 7691097
515612 7702192 
516655 7704405
519788 7713255 
538466 7683341
```

Where I am stuck is how to get these values for Easting (left) and Northing (right) into the easting and northing lists. Can someone please help with this as I am completely unsure of how to get them into the easting and northing lists that are in main2()

Also am I implementing the function correctly by calling the values of easting and northing from the easting and northing lists?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So, just clarifying, you want all the values on the left side in a separate list? And all the ones on a right in a separate list?

Comment: @Haidro yes thats it please. I want to put all the values on the left into a eastlist=[] and all the values on the right into a northlist= [] is this possible?/ where would I implement this?

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am assuming `getStationCoords()` returns:

```
[['476050', '7709929'], ['473971', '7707713'], ['465676', '7691097'], ['515612', '7702192'], ['516655', '7704405'], ['519788', '7713255'], ['538466', '7683341']]
```

You can use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
eastlist, northlist = [map(int, i) for i in zip(*getStationCoords())]
print eastlist
# [476050, 473971, 465676, 515612, 516655, 519788, 538466]
print northlist
# [7709929, 7707713, 7691097, 7702192, 7704405, 7713255, 7683341]
```

Wherever you implement this is entirely up to you, as you are the one writing the code :p.

Comment: Thank you @Haidro this is perfect I was thinking I may need to split the values up earlier but if the list already exists then zip is a better method. Love your work and your Mudkip. Thanks

Comment: im trying to implement this by calling from the list however it wont work for strings and int if i use - is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I.e can i remove them from strings in the list somehow?

Comment: @KristoferWright Do you want them as integers instead of strings?

Comment: yes please can they be integers in the list and not strings? Is this possible